# Time Delay for a process in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have to give the delay for the process to happen, which I am calling in the Update function.
I have tried CoUpdate workaround also. Here is my code:-

```
function Start() 
{
  StartCoroutine("CoStart"); 
} 
function CoStart() : IEnumerator 
{ 
  while(true) 
  { 
    yield CoUpdate(); 
  } 
} 
function CoUpdate() 
{ 
  //I have placed the code of the Update(). 
  //And called the wait function wherever needed. 
} 
function wait() 
{ 
   checkOnce=1; //Whenever the character is moved. 
   yield WaitForSeconds(2); //Delay of 2 seconds. 
}
```

I have to move an object when a third person controller(which is another object) moves out of a boundary. I have included "yield" in my code. But, the problem happening is: The object which was moving when I gave the code for in the Update(), is moving, but isn't stopping. And it is moving up and down. I don't know what is happening! Can someone help? Please, thanks.

Comment: You should add some info about how the object moves. So far, I cannot see a relationship between the use of coroutines and your object movement. And, by the way, I don't think this is the right approach for your problem, seeing how convoluted it is.

Comment: Use IEnumerator functions and you can put delay in those with yield WaitForSeconds(n).

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, but I can show you how to set up a Time Delay for a coroutine. For this example lets work with a simple cool down, much like you set up in your example. Assuming you want to continuously do something every 2 seconds while your game is running a slight modification can be made to your code.

```
function Start()
{
   StartCoroutine(CoStart);
}

function CoStart() : IEnumerator
{
   while(true)
   {
      //.. place your logic here

      // function will sleep for two seconds before starting this loop again
      yield WaitForSeconds(2);   
   }
}
```

You can also calculate a wait time using some other logic

```
function Start()
{
   StartCoroutine(CoStart);
}

function CoStart() : IEnumerator
{
   while(true)
   {
      //.. place your logic here

      // function will sleep for two seconds before starting this loop again
      yield WaitForSeconds(CalculateWait());   
   }
}

function CalculateWait() : float
{

   // use some logic here to determine the amount of time to wait for the 
   // next CoStart cycle to start
   return someFloat;
}
```

If I have missed the mark entirely then please update the question with a more detail about what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I understand you question but if you want to start one object to move when the other is out of bound then just make a reference in the first object to the second object and when the first object is out of bounds (check for this in Update of the first object) call some public function StartMove on the second object.

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't suggest CoRoutines. It can sometimes crash your computer. Just define a variable and decrement it. Example:

```
private float seconds = 5;
```

then do anywhere you want to delay:

```
seconds -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
if(seconds <= 0) {your code to run}
```

This will make a delay of 5 seconds. You can change 5 to any value to change the number of seconds. Also you can speed up the decrement by changing the value of 1. (This is mostly useful when you want to sync 2 delayed actions, by using the same variable)

Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: Coroutines cannot crash your computer.

Comment: Coroutines will not crash your computer.